# NoClassDefFound Error with viewpager adapter using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implementes Fragments to use in a viewpager with TabStrib, i had problems with Fragment imports so i'm not quite sure if the problem is there in any way.

These are my imports:

```
 package com.dev.lhexpress;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class ExpressSlideActivity extends Activity {

        ExpressFragmentAdapter adapterViewPager;
        ViewPager vpPager;
        FragmentManager fm;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.express_screen_slide);
            vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.express_pager);
            adapterViewPager = new ExpressFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
            vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

        }


        public static class ExpressFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
                private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

                public ExpressFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return NUM_ITEMS;
                }

                // Returns the fragment to display for that page
                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0: 
                        return GeneralFragment.newInstance(0, "General");
                    case 1: 
                        return FavoritesFragment.newInstance(1, "Favoritos");
                    case 2: 
                        return HistoryFragment.newInstance(2, "Historial");
                    default:
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                // Returns the page title for the top indicator
                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    return "Page " + position;
                }

            }
    }`
```

and this is the logcat that i'm getting running it:

```
   05-26 17:45:04.122: W/System(20847): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dev.lhexpress-1/lib/arm
05-26 17:45:04.152: W/ResourceType(20847): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a93 (t=7 e=2707) (error -75)
05-26 17:45:04.262: I/Timeline(20847): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.dev.lhexpress time:23772183
05-26 17:45:04.302: D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(20847): Metadata value : none
05-26 17:45:04.312: D/ViewRootImpl(20847): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{c9b0504 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-26 17:45:04.312: D/OpenGLRenderer(20847): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-26 17:45:04.372: E/ViewSystem(20847): ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
05-26 17:45:04.372: I/art(20847): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity$ExpressFragmentAdapter>
05-26 17:45:04.372: I/art(20847): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity$ExpressFragmentAdapter>
05-26 17:45:04.382: W/ResourceType(20847): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a93 (t=7 e=2707) (error -75)
05-26 17:45:04.452: I/art(20847): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9855(685KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 8.716ms total 57.983ms
05-26 17:45:04.492: I/art(20847): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity$ExpressFragmentAdapter>
05-26 17:45:04.492: D/AndroidRuntime(20847): Shutting down VM
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847): Process: com.dev.lhexpress, PID: 20847
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity$ExpressFragmentAdapter
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity.onCreate(ExpressSlideActivity.java:24)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
05-26 17:45:04.492: E/AndroidRuntime(20847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I'll very thankful if someone can help me with this, my mind is blowing

Comment: Where is the package of your class?

Comment: sorry i miss to put it in, it's before the imports package com.dev.lhexpress;

Comment: This error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dev.lhexpress.ExpressSlideActivity$ExpressFragmentAdapter`, Where is your `ExpressFragmentAdapter`? Can you show us the project structure?